# How to bring NULL value even after Join is present in MYSQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables named as DEPARTMENT_MASTER AND DIVISION_MASTER in MySQL Database.

```
DEPARTMENT_MASTER              DIVISION_MASTER
DEPT_ID | DEPT_NAME            DIVISION_ID | DIVISION_NAME | DEPT_ID
1       | HR                   1           | DIV1          | 1
2       | CLINICAL             2           | DIV2          | 1
3       | IT                   3           | DIV3          | 2
```

I have this simple SQL query as -

```
SELECT DM.DEPT_NAME, DV.DIVISION_NAME, DM.DEPT_ID, DV.DIVISION_ID 
FROM DEPARTMENT_MASTER DM 
LEFT JOIN DIVISION_MASTER DV ON DM.DEPT_ID = DV.DEPT_ID
```

So for that i get result like this

```
DEPT_NAME | DIVISION_NAME | DEPT_ID | DIVISION_ID
HR        | DIV1          | 1       | 1
HR        | DIV2          | 1       | 2
CLINICAL  | DIV3          | 2       | 3
IT        | NULL          | 3       | NULL
```

Is there any way so that i can get result like this-

```
DEPT_NAME | DIVISION_NAME | DEPT_ID | DIVISION_ID
HR        | NULL          | 1       | NULL
HR        | DIV1          | 1       | 1
HR        | DIV2          | 1       | 2
CLINICAL  | NULL          | 2       | NULL
CLINICAL  | DIV3          | 2       | 3
IT        | NULL          | 3       | NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a `UNION` with a query that returns all the null values you want.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DM.DEPT_NAME, DV.DIVISION_NAME, DM.DEPT_ID, DV.DIVISION_ID 
    FROM DEPARTMENT_MASTER DM 
    LEFT JOIN DIVISION_MASTER DV ON DM.DEPT_ID = DV.DEPT_ID
    UNION 
    SELECT DEPT_NAME, NULL, DEPT_ID, NULL
    FROM DEPARTMENT_MASTER) AS x
ORDER BY DEPT_NAME, DIVISION_NAME
```

But in this case, you might as well use `INNER JOIN`, since the `UNION` will add null rows for both the matching and non-matching rows.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DM.DEPT_NAME, DV.DIVISION_NAME, DM.DEPT_ID, DV.DIVISION_ID 
    FROM DEPARTMENT_MASTER DM 
    INNER JOIN DIVISION_MASTER DV ON DM.DEPT_ID = DV.DEPT_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DEPT_NAME, NULL, DEPT_ID, NULL
    FROM DEPARTMENT_MASTER) AS x
ORDER BY DEPT_NAME, DIVISION_NAME
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how can i use ORDER BY in above query(1st one) according to DEPT_NAME

Comment: Put it in a subquery and use `ORDER BY` in the main query. I've updated the answer to show this.